# Permitting parameters in an array (form with multiple instances of the same model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form which shows all entries of a model

```
<%= form_tag some_path(@entity), method: :put do |f| %>
  <%  @skill_levels.each_with_index do |skill_level, index| %>
    <%= fields_for "skill_level[#{skill_level.id}]", skill_level do |skill_level_fields| %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This gives me the following params

```
params.require(:skill_level)
<ActionController::Parameters 
  {"1"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"value", "entity_id"=>"", "id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"} permitted: false>,
  "2"=>{"name"=>"value", "entity_id"=>"", "id"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"false"}, 
  "3"=>{"name"=>"value", "entity_id"=>"", "id"=>"3", "_destroy"=>"false"}} permitted: false>
```

Ho can I properly permit these parameters which are within an array? I've tried many variants like this

```
params.require(:skill_level).permit([])
params.require(:skill_level).permit([:name,:id,:entity_id])
```

Comment: have your tried    params.require(:skill_category).permit([:name,:id])

Comment: Yes, I've tried it already. The output is as follows: <ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>